# Laravel 5.4 Basic Authentication without a database

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, basic-authentication, laravel-5.4

**Problem:** I need to implement a basic authentication on my API created with Laravel 5.4. Since we need to implement it without a database (just getting credentials from `config()`), I tried to create a registered middleware like the following one:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

class AuthenticateOnceWithBasicAuth
{
    public function handle($request, $next)
    {
        if($request->getUser() != conf('auth.credentials.user') && $request->getPassword() != conf('auth.credentials.pass')) {
            $headers = array('WWW-Authenticate' => 'Basic');
            return response('Unauthorized', 401, $headers);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

It works, but this way I can only have one credentials for the whole API.
I've tried to create more then one credentials in the config, saving user and password from request, but this way, it works like basic auth is disabled.

**Question:** is there any way to achieve this? How can I have multiple credentials in my config file, without using a database?

Comment: There is an issue with this code! You are returning 401 only in the case that both username AND password does not match. If a user provides a valid username, but invalid password he gets authenticated. you should use || instead of &&

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can save your authorized usernames and password in your config file as a Collection.

`config/myconfig.php`

```
return [
        'authorized_identities' => collect([
             ['user1','password1'],
             ['user2','password2'],
             ...
        ]),
];
```

and then in your middleware

```
if(config('myconfig.authorized_identites')->contains([$request->getUser(),$request->getPassword()]))
```

Comment: Another option is to put it into a singleton.

Comment: i am using Lumen 5.6 and config() returns an array, so collect(config()) is the safest way IMO

Comment: It gives below error

In ConfigCacheCommand.php line 71:

  Your configuration files are not serializable.


In Macroable.php line 76:

  Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::__set_state does not exist.

Comment: That error means you have a closure in your configuration file, at the time of writing the above code, the `collect()` method was allowed in the configuration file, try to remove it and/or remove any closure you added in your configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an array of credentials and try to match the input with anyone of them and validate. To be honest you could easily implement this with a sqlite database. It requires minimalistic setup and you can get started and use it within 5 mins.

Comment: It could be the case where he cant use a sqlite db either, since that requires sqlite3. But I agree with the array approach, should be simple enough.